# Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a regular expression, when I check the following regex online, it works correctly. However, it return error in php. Why is that?

```
preg_match_all('/^[([a-z]+\[[a-z| |,]+\])\,?]+$/', $methods, $result);
```

return

```
Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 23
```

I tried this one too:

```
preg_match_all('/^[([a-z]+\\[[a-z| |,]+\\])\\,?]+$/', $methods, $result);
```

Comment: How are you "checking it online," and are you sure that this online tool is checking PHP regex syntax? What version of PHP are you using when you get the error?

Comment: @MattBall php is tagged, also preg_match_all is a php function

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco yes, I am aware `:)` thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of string you wish to match ?

Comment: @MattBall, just saying, besaides, if is helpfull to anyone i regularly use this to test my regex http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco [I can repro the warning](http://ideone.com/JBq1cr), so I suspected that part of the problem lies with whichever online regex tool the OP used.

Comment: mmm its legal to have the `[]` nested? (sorry i dont remember hor are they called in english)

Answer (score 2):

if you change the outer Character class (`[]`) by character group (parentheses) it will compile, but im not sure what kind of string are you trying to match:

```
/^(([a-z]+\[[a-z| |,]+\])\,?)+$/
```

like in this [example](http://ideone.com/f3Dwua)

i think this is caused because you cant put nested Character class because they will lose their meaning so your regex ends in 3 parts like this:

```
[([a-z]+

\[[a-z| |,]+

\])\,?]+
```

ending in unmatched enter parentheses

Comment: Character class. Having nested character classes is meaningless so there is no syntax for it. Inside of a character class, `]` is a metacharacter and will be interpreted as ending the character class unless escaped, while `[` is just normal. http://regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: thanks i know how are the called in spanish, but i dont found the reference in inglish and i didnt belived that it was the literal translation